# Django. ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, django, path, structure, project

I'm a newbie. And I just started writing a django project. It is called the iRayProject and consists of two applications iRay_user_authentication and iRay_working_with_notes:
[project structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJbPn.png)

iRay_user_authentication - this is a standard django app for registration

Here is his urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import login_user, registration

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_user, name='login_user'),
    path('registration', registration, name='registration'),
]
```

In views.py registered user using redirect I want to send to the second application of the project

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from ..iRay_working_with_notes.views import list_notes


def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'iRay_user_authentication/login.html', {'form': AuthenticationForm})


def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'iRay_user_authentication/registration.html', {'form': UserCreationForm})
    else:
        if '_guest' in request.POST:
            pass
        else:
            if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                    user.save()
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect(list_notes)
                except IntegrityError:
                    return render(request, 'iRay_user_authentication/registration.html', {'form': UserCreationForm,
                                                                                          'error': 'name is busy '
                                                                                          })
            else:
                return render(request, 'todo_app/registration.html', {'form': UserCreationForm,
                                                                      'error': 'passwords not math'})
```

But when trying to import a function from the second views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def list_notes(request):
    return render(request, 'iRay_working_with_notes/list_notes.html')
```

I get an error:

*ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package*

And I found a lot of theoretical information about why this error occurs.
But I still couldn 't figure out if there is an easy way for relative or absolute import , or I just didn 't structure my project correctly ??

Comment: You should put the modules you are executing into the root folder of your project. The folder the resist in will be added to `PYTHONPATH` and become the import base.

Comment: Redirects do not take a view function but a url conf name and optionally arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. import is wrong

```
from ..iRay_working_with_notes.views import list_notes
```

should be

```
from iRay_working_with_notes.views import list_notes
```

2. redirect needs view name from the urls-pattern:

```
redirect('name-of-my-view-pattern')
```

So please create a url-pattern entry for the list_notes view and give the pattern name as parameter to the redirect.

Why? because a redirect is telling the browser on the client side to load the target redirect page, so it needs an url (that is generated by django via the url-pattern), as the target page will be called from the browser.

Technically of course you can import a view and call it from another module directly as it is just a python function - but that is not a http redirect (and would not change the url in the browser to the redirected page) and additionally that is not really the idea of the django request/response architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
PyCharm shows an error in the line:  from iRay_working_with_notes.views import list_notes   But it works

Comment: in PyCharm -> right click on iRayProject and mark as source folder ... then Pycharm error will go away